# Is "..., so (adjective) is (noun)." a valid construction?

Tags: word-order

Let's assume that *The use of cars is so prevalent that we cannot imagine life without them* is a good sentence.

My question is whether *We cannot image life without cars, so prevalent is their use*  is a correct sentence and equivalent to the first one.

I feel like it is, but I cannot name the grammatical usage involved.

Comment: Try rephrasing it: "We cannot image life without cars, their usage is so vast." This is a comma splice therefore an invalid construction. To fix it, merely insert a semi-colon in place of the comma.

Comment: Or another solution: replace *is* with *being*, thus making the independent clause into a dependent one: 'We cannot image life without cars, their usage being so vast' or 'We cannot image life without cars, so vast being their usage'

Comment: No, I disagree with @V0ight. The inversion makes this a subordinate clause, so it is perfectly acceptable (and well established as a literary form).

Comment: @Colin Fine ~ How exactly is 'so prevalent is their use' a subordinate clause? It's a complete sentence in its own right.

Comment: @V0ight It's subordinate by virtue of its function in the larger construction. I'd say it was a reason adjunct (adverbial)

Comment: There's quite a big difference in the syntax of your two examples. In the first one, the _that_ clause is an indirect complement licenced by the "so" that modifies "prevalent". In the second one, the _their_ clause is a reason adjunct (adverbial), i.e. it is optional.

Comment: @BillJ ~ I guess I could see how that could be the case, but it still looks wrong to me for some reason. What's stopping the "their usage is so prevalent" (in my first comment) from being an adverbial clause as well then?

Comment: @V0ight I'd say your example would also be an adjunct (adverbial).

Comment: @BillJ ~ well congrats, you flipped my world on its head.

Comment: @V0ight For the avoidance of doubt, my message commencing with "There's" was for the OP.

Comment: Example of this construction, from [_Dracula_}(https://books.google.com/books?id=Ceq0CwAAQBAJ&pg=PA180&dq=%22so+quickly+did%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi746GKj4DOAhVLBcAKHfq8AHw4FBDoAQg_MAY): "For answer he seemed to throw himself off the box, so quickly did he reach the ground."

Comment: It's good teaching practice to stick with straightforward examples, avoiding literary examples.

Answer (score 2):

This article on inversion, from [Perfect English Grammar.com](http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/inversion.html) [corrected and modified], explains the construction and the transformation involved:

> 4: We use inversion after 'so + adjective' where later followed by 'that':
>
> *So beautiful was the girl that nobody could talk of anything else.* (Normal sentence: the girl was so beautiful that nobody could talk of
>   anything else.)
>
> *So delicious was the food that we ate every last bite.* (Normal sentence: the food was so delicious that we ate every last bite.)

The inverted variants are rather old-fashioned or of a literary register. Equally so is the further re-ordering:

> So prevalent is the use of cars that we cannot imagine life without
>   them.
>
> We cannot image life without cars, so prevalent is their use.

The terminal positioning of the clause giving the reason is acceptable; here is an example from Belloc (The Path to Rome - Page 245):

> Above the soft bed which the hay made, a square window, unglazed, gave
>   upon the southern night; the mist hardly drifted in or past it, so
>   still was the air.

Comment: ........................addressed.